# How to make a keyboard font with TTF files into a language?

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I'm trying to change the US English input language keyboard "ENG" on my laptop to a custom TTF front that im using on Keyman Developer.

I found a font with cool alien letters and symbols and im trying to make that into a language i can use to type with.

Keyman Developer so far didn't show me such an option is available thus i need help.

Keyman Developer doesn't show me an option to do that.

Tried using Microsoft keyboard layout creator, and it gave me errors while trying to save the font.

Comment: Sorry, you're question is not clear. Are you talking about a font (used to display characters), or about a keyboard (used to input characters)?